# ERROR: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Tags: android, servicio

Tengo un problema y no sé la causa. Una aplicación simple de escanear las redes Wi-Fi. Ésta puede servir de referencia:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883162/get-available-wi-fi-scan-result-in-customized-listview

En mi móvil antiguo (v5.1) funciona correctamente, pero en el nuevo (v10) no, no se rompe la aplicación ni da error de compilación, sólamente que no muestra nada.

Da la impresión de que se debe a la versión de Android, he probado diferentes configuraciones de Android Studio, pero nada ¿Hay alguna librería obsoleta?

SAMSUNG M11 (Android 10) LOG:

```
03/28 20:09:56: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
Install successfully finished in 3 s 220 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "es.josecarlos.myapplication/es.josecarlos.myapplication.SearchWifi" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 29558 on device 'samsung-sm_m115f-R9JR30FM7HJ'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/s.myapplicatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/s.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf:: Perf HAL Service is not available.
E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf:: Perf HAL Service is not available.
E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf:: Perf HAL Service is not available.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/s.myapplicatio: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/s.myapplicatio: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/s.myapplicatio: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ClassLinker for 20.796ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
D/PhoneWindow: forceLight changed to true [] from com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4238 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1490 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3216 android.view.Window.setFlags:1148 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2444 
I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@9ffef9d[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@9ffef9d[]
W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@9ffef9d TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1560) new=(0,0,720,1560) req=(720,1560)0 dur=14 res=0x7 s={true 3550955520} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 0xd3a8e0c0, 0xd3a74800
I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : 2ced3f2, Id01cc02572
    Build Date                       : 12/15/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.6.2.R1.10.00.00.537.049
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S L 8.0.10 AArch32
D/AbsListView:  in onLayout changed 
I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@9ffef9d[SearchWifi]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@9ffef9d[SearchWifi]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=es.josecarlos.myapplication ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,720,1560) ci=(0,65,0,84) vi=(0,65,0,84) or=1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@9ffef9d[SearchWifi]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=es.josecarlos.myapplication ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@73bc89c[SearchWifi]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@47f6701[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout@76759a6 TM=true MM=false
V/Toast: Text: Fsca in android.widget.Toast$TN@b5efe7
D/ViewRootImpl@47f6701[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=(0,65,720,1476) new=(232,1287,488,1364) req=(256,77)0 dur=12 res=0x7 s={true 3550953472} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 0xb8abc140, 0xd3a74000
D/ViewRootImpl@47f6701[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=(232,1287,488,1364) ci=(0,0,0,0) vi=(0,0,256,77) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@47f6701[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'c01175c', fd=75
```

SAMSUNG J3 (Android 5.1) LOG:

```
03/28 20:19:39: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
Install successfully finished in 1 m 15 s 28 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "es.josecarlos.myapplication/es.josecarlos.myapplication.SearchWifi" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 8248 on device 'samsung-sm_j320fn-42000d659a379400'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/es.josecarlos.myapplication-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in es.josecarlos.myapplication rsrc of package es.josecarlos.myapplication
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
    fillFeatureStoreMap es.josecarlos.myapplication
I/InjectionManager: Constructor es.josecarlos.myapplication, Feature store :{}
    featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/es.josecarlos.myapplication-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in es.josecarlos.myapplication rsrc of package es.josecarlos.myapplication
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/es.josecarlos.myapplication-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in es.josecarlos.myapplication rsrc of package es.josecarlos.myapplication
    getTopLevelResources: /data/app/es.josecarlos.myapplication-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in es.josecarlos.myapplication rsrc of package es.josecarlos.myapplication
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
    *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
    Failure getting entry for 0x01080946 (t=7 e=2374) (error -75)
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
    motionService = null
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : es.josecarlos.myapplication.SearchWifi isFragment :false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
    *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
    Enabling debug mode 0
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :es.josecarlos.myapplication.SearchWifi
    dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :es.josecarlos.myapplication.SearchWifi
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@117c6e4b time:365818
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución.

Hay que añadir el permiso **FINE_LOCATION** y:

1. Conceder los permisos de ubicación desde Ajustes a la aplicación

o

2. Crear un menú popup para que la primera vez que se lanza la aplicación, el usuario acepte conceder los permisos.